# Identity involving the number pi

Tags: limits, pi

Why is this identity true?

$\pi$ = $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}}  $

Where the number of two's inside the big square root is equal to n.